# Python: get the max value with the location above and below than the max

Tags: python, dataframe, data-preprocessing

If I have a dataframe like this,

```
index  User    Value  location
 1      1      1.0    4.5 
 2      1      1.5    5.2
 3      1      3.0    7.0
 4      1      2.5    7.5
 5      2      1.0    11.5
 6      2      1.25   14.1
 7      2      2.0    13.0
 8      2      3.5    14.0
 9      3      2.0    2.4
 10     3      3.5    4.3
 11     3      1.0    5.4
 12     3      3.0    5.3
 13     4      1.0    11.0
 14     4      3.0    12.3
```

How would I select the max VALUE for each user with the nearest neighbor (above and lower) location of the max location, and if there's only one nearest location of the max, retrieve them as well?

The final results should be like this,

```
index  User   Value  location 
 2      1      1.5    5.2
 3      1      3.0    7.0
 4      1      2.5    7.5
 6      2      1.25   14.1
 7      2      2.0    13.0
 8      2      3.5    14.0
 9      3      2.0    2.4
 10     3      3.5    4.3
 12     3      3.0    5.3
 13     4      1.0    11.0
 14     4      3.0    12.3
```

Comment: There will be no values larger than the max.  I think you're trying to keep the top three entries for each user.  Is that right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# df = "your_data_frame"

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [],
                       "User": [],
                       "Value": []})

for user in sorted(list(set(df['User'].to_list()))):
  new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df[df['User'] == user].nlargest(3, 'location')])
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.nlargest(n, colname)` will automatically return < n values if there are less than n available.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure my answer still solves it--I just updated it to look for the max three values in the "location" column.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that, the location isn't necessary has to be the largest. For example in user 3, it should be one below and one upper the max.

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding you here: what do you mean by "one upper the max?" Isn't the max by definition the highest possible value for location for user 3? This is the same question Tim Roberts asked in the comments. I see that you are actually looking to select the lowest possible values for that column--is there another criterion I'm missing here?

Comment: I meant select max from the value and get the nearest neighbor (above and below) the max location. For example, the max value for User 3 is 3.5. I want to get the nearest location for 3.5 location (4.3) which will retrieve 2.4 and 5.3. I hope this will make it clear. Thanks!